# How to log to user's ApplicationData folder using Enterprise Library Logging?

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library

I'm using MS EnterpriseLibrary.Logging and that works perfectly but the log file(s) are placed in the program executable directory.

How do I get it to place my log files in individual user's applicationData folder?

The folder I'm talking about is the one you get by calling:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use environment variables in your logfile path.  I believe that `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` would be equivalent to `%APPDATA%`.

So you can set the fileName to: **%APPDATA%\MyApplication\Logs\trace.log**
The directory structure will also be created for you at runtime so you don't have to explicitly create the folders.

The configuration file would look something like:

```
  <add fileName="%APPDATA%\MyApplication\Logs\trace.log" header=""
    footer="" formatter="Text Formatter"     
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    name="Flat File Destination" />
```